# Extjs 4.2.1 - config autoLoad:false Fails

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I define a `treepanel` extend `extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel'` and that has initComponent function like

```
 Ext.define('Example', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    title: 'Example',
    useArrows:false, 
    rootVisible: false,
    border: false,
    initComponent: function () {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            fields: [
                {name: 'id',     type: 'string'},
                {name: 'text',     type: 'string'}
            ],
            autoLoad : false, // not working
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'results'     
                }
            }

        });
        this.store = store;
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
 });
```

I try to set `autoLoad: false` but that always loading when i create my `treepanel`

When i try to config below code to store then `autoLoad: false` working but my `treepanel` after load is blank

```
                root: {
                    text: 'Ext JS',
                    id: 'src',
                    expanded: false // this 
                }
```

my json is good and working if not using `root` config like

```
({  "results": [
    { 
        id : '1' , 
        text : '1', 
        expanded: true, 
        results :[{ 
            id : '2' , 
            text : '2', 
            leaf:true
        }]
    },{ 
        id : '3' , 
        text : '3', 
        leaf:true
    }] 
})
```

How to fix that thanks.

Comment: The autoLoad property is only bound to the store itself. I guess in your case a component triggers the load. If you want full control you can check every load with the `beforeload` event and return false if it is not `valid`

Comment: @sra How to check if not `valid`, what do u mean? But why my code fails, `autoLoad : false` is not working :(

Comment: Please reffer to the docs for [autoLoad](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-cfg-autoLoad) Note that if `true` the store will load after it is created. Create just the store without the treepanel and you will see that your store don't load after creation.

Comment: @sra if using `beforeload` i think that's hard to catch. i using `root: {
    results: []
}` in `store` then `autoLoad: false` working but when i `load()` my `treepanel` is blank?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to override `Ext.tree.Panel.setRootNode` metod to take store's `autoLoad` property into account.

The following example is tested with ExtJS v4.2.2.

```
Ext.define('Example', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    title: 'Example',
    useArrows:false,
    rootVisible: false,
    border: false,

    /**
     * Override.
     */
    setRootNode: function() {
        if (this.getStore().autoLoad) {
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            fields: [
                {name: 'id',     type: 'string'},
                {name: 'text',     type: 'string'}
            ],
            autoLoad : false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/data.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'results'
                }
            }

        });
        this.store = store;
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function(){

    var tree = Ext.create('Example', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    });

    tree.getStore().load();
});
```

Comment: Is this is a bug in 4.2.2?  This wasn't happening in 4.1.1 for me

Comment: @HDave seems so. Views for tables and trees were slightly refactored.

Answer (score 4):

i don't know why "autoLoad: false;" does not work.
but you can prevent autoloading as **adding 'root' config in treepanel**. not in treestore.
and also **load()** works correctly.

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',

    .....

    root: {
        loaded: true;
    }
}
```

this will work.

```
var myTreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    fields: [ ... ],

    proxy: { ... },

    root: {
        loaded: true;
    }
});
```

this will not work.

good luck.

Comment: Yes, this works. Imo it's a weird side-effect or bug?. At the end I send the same data to the store. Tested this in Extjs 5.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly you might just be looking for queryMode: 'local', I'm not 100% it works for this but that's what I would do..

I use that on comboboxes all the time, it forces local store management (turns off autoLoad)